# Java server socket with NAT and Dynamic DNS

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, dns, nat

I'm trying to develop a server side program in Java for a data collection project.

Here's the architecture:

I have a remote electronic device which collects data periodically and sends it back to the server. This device is equipped with a SIM card which has GPRS connection activated, so it can be considered as a computer with internet access. Before sending data back to the server, it has to know the IP address of the server.

As it's too expensive to have a static IP via my ISP, I've then decided to try dynamic DNS(DDNS). I've installed the DDNS client on my PC and configured the port forwarding in my router as follows:

```
External Port Start: 33333
External Port End: 33333
Protocol: TCP
Internal Port Start: 33333
Internal Port End: 33333
Server IP Address: 192.168.0.100 // My PC's IP Adress.
```

Then I've tried to run a simple server/client program on my PC (Yeah, both of them on the same PC). They do nothing complicated, just sending and receiving some strings using `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` class.

The client can connect to the server, and the server can accept the connection (port forwarding works ?!). But when they try to read or send data, both of them throw an IOException. The server says `Connection reset` and a few seconds later, the client gets `timeout`.

It seems that when the server accepts a new connection, they will pick an arbitrary new port number which is not specified in port forwarding settings, is it the problem ?

I'd like to know what's the actual cause of the IOException, why they cannot read or write data, and any suggestion for fixing the issue ?

Thanks a lot.

**Code of server:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread
{
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;

   public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException
   {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
   }

   public void run()
   {
      while(true)
      {
         try
         {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
            serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Just connected to "
                  + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream in =
                  new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            DataOutputStream out =
                 new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to "
              + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
            server.close();
         }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
         {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
         }catch(IOException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int port = 33333;
      try
      {
         Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
         t.start();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

**Code of client:**
`xxxxxxx.xicp.net` is my free domain name, and the server listens to port `33333`.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingClient
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      InetAddress ip;
      String serverName;
      int port = 33333;
      try
      {
         ip = InetAddress.getByName("xxxxxxx.xicp.net");
         serverName = ip.getHostAddress();
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName
                             + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(ip, port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to "
                      + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out =
                       new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

         out.writeUTF("Hello from "
                      + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
         InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in =
                        new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
         client.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think external port start should be 0 and external port end should be 65535.  Typically the client's OS will randomly choose a port to use to make the outgoing connection.  You are telling the client to connect to your router's public IP on port 33333, but the port that it chooses to use as the source could be anything.

Comment: The close() in the client closes the connection.  Have you tried running both server and client in the same JVM and adding some println statements to see in what order events are happening?

Comment: @NormR Yes, both programs are run on the same PC, so in the same JVM. Before closing the socket, client has to send a Hello message to server, and then waits for server's reply. But the program crashed before message transmission.

Comment: @mti2935 Have tried 1-65535, but it doesn't work. Server still reset the connection and the client is always timeout. The client prints `Connecting to 174.128.255.227 on port 33333` and the IP address is always the same. However the server prints `Just connected to /114.43.16.250:6000`, both IP address and port change everytime. I just don't get it.

Comment: @vesintio You said: on the same PC, so in the same JVM  How do you do that?  When I do it, I have another main() method that calls the main() methods for the Server and the Client classes from threads.  All print outs then are in time sequence in the one JVM that is running my special main.

Comment: @NormR As you can see, the server and client are two different programs, I just run them in 2 two command prompts, ok maybe they are not in the same JVM. But that's not the point, I just don't understand why the client can connect to the server, but when they try to exchange data with each other, they throw IOException. Usually it's due to the disconnection, but I've no idea where the problem comes from.

Comment: My guess: I've NAT configured in my router, so all incoming connection is forwarded to the port 33333 of my PC. Once the client is connected to the server, it will pick an other port, e.g. 5000, to communicate with the server. When the server tries to send something to the client, it sends it to port 5000. AS in NAT setting the port 5000 is not forwarded, the transmission fails. I'm not sure, need to be tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess: I've NAT configured in my router, so all incoming connection is forwarded to the
>   port 33333 of my PC. Once the client is connected to the server, it will pick an other port,
>   e.g. 5000, to communicate with the server. When the server tries to send something to the
>   client, it sends it to port 5000. AS in NAT setting the port 5000 is not forwarded, the
>   transmission fails. I'm not sure, need to be tested.

Ok, it's confirmed. I've tried to run the client on my laptop using a my phone's 3G connection, and the server on my desktop PCconnected to the router. The port 33333 is forworded to the desktop PC. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a while ago, but I have/had the same problem with my connections at first too.

Your problem stems from closing your DataOuputStream/DataInputStream flows. Basically you want to keep them open and when done writing call flush.

This could be problematic for the either connection however, if you try to read more bytes than have been sent. I suggest throwing an message 'header' into your code (also called a sentinel) to tell the receiving party how many bytes it will read.

Also for quick data traversal try BufferedOutputStream/BufferedInputStream, the speed increase is incredible.